# Ubuntu Installer crashes when Checking for packages to install

Tags: boot

I first used Unetbootin on my Mac to create a bootable USB drive for Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. However, the installer crashed during the installation process. It went smoothly until the step "Checking for packages to install", right after "Configuring hardware". My laptop is a ThinkPad x230. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think its a hardware issue, there might have been some faults during bootable drive creation. Try downloading [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and recreating the bootable drive from scratch.

Comment: And, please post what error you're getting. Without that, we won't be of much help.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used rufus and I have installed Ubuntu successfully! Thanks again.